# Similar product in AWS or GCP like Azure Data Factory?

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, google-cloud-platform, azure-data-factory

I am totaly new to the cloud in any way. I started some weeks ago with the Azure cloud and we setting up a project using many different products of Azure.
At the moment we think about setting up the project on a way that we are not trapped by Microsoft and are able to switch to GCP or AWS. For most products we use I have found similar ones in the other Clouds but I wonder if there is somthing like Azure Data Factory in AWS or CGP? I could not find something in my first google research.

Best and thanks for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need a good comparison between different cloud (Azure, AWS, Google, Oracle, and Alibaba) use this site: http://comparecloud.in/

Example for your case with "Azure Data Factory":

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use a mix of those products:

- [Cloud Data Fusion]https://cloud.google.com/composer
- Cloud DataPrep: This is a version of [Trifacta](https://trifacta.com). Good for data cleaning.

If you need to orchestrate workflows / etls, [Cloud composer](https://cloud.google.com/composer) will do it for you. It is a managed [Apache Airflow](https://airflow.apache.org/). Which means it will handle complex dependencies.

If you just need to trigger a job on a daily basis, Cloud Scheduler is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the link [here](http://osamaoracle.com/2020/06/19/services-mapping-aws-azure-gcp-oc-ibm-and-alibab-cloud/) which is cloud services mapping