# How to include data from one powerbi report in another?

Tags: powerbi

I am working at a company where one team has a report with data and a table. I'd like to take that table and some of that data and use it in my team's report. I'm new to powerBI in general. Is there any way to do this other than getting access to the data source that the team is using?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you publish a Power BI report, you automatically create a dataset. This very dataset can also be used for other reports (see "Get data" > "Power BI datasets").

**Little side note #1:** Said dataset does not include calculated columns or measures.

**Little side note #2:** If you're aiming to use the same transformations for a number of reports, also consider taking a more structured approach using tools such as, e.g.,

- Azure Data Factory: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/introduction --> probably the easiest to integrate
- AWS Glue: https://aws.amazon.com/glue/
- GCP Cloud Composer: https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/

and many, many more

Also, refer to [this discussion on tools to perform ETL/ELT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63574327/similar-product-in-aws-or-gcp-like-azure-data-factory)